# Best way to test a mailer with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mailer

I have a mailer that passes an argument like so:

```
AnimalMailer.daily_message(owner).deliver_later
```

The method looks like this:

AnimalMailer

```
class AnimalMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def daily_message(owner)
     mail(
      to: "#{user.name}",
      subject: "test",
      content_type: "text/html",
      date: Time.now.in_time_zone("Mountain Time (US & Canada)")
    )
  end
end
```

I'm new to writing specs and was wondering how should I pass the owner to the method and test it. I currently have this set up:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe AnimalMailer, type: :mailer do
  
  describe "monthly_animal_message" do
    let(:user) { create(:user, :admin) }

    it "renders the headers" do
      expect(mail.subject).to eq("test")
      expect(mail.to).to eq(user.name)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specs generally follow a three-step flow 1) set up, 2) invoke, 3) expect. This applies for unit testing mailers like anything else. The invocation and parameters are the same in the test as for general use, so in your case:

```rb
RSpec.describe AnimalMailer, type: :mailer do  
  describe "monthly_campaign_report" do
    let(:user) { create(:user, :admin) }
    let(:mail) { described_class.daily_message(user) }  # invocation

    it 'renders the headers' do
      expect(mail.subject).to eq('test')
      expect(mail.to).to eq(user.name)
    end

    it 'renders the body' do
      # whatever
    end
  end
end
```

Note that since the `describe` is the class name being tested, you can use `described_class` from there to refer back to the described class. You can always use `AnimalMailer.daily_message` as well, but among other things `described_class` ensures that if you shuffle or share examples that you are always testing what you think you are.

Also note that in the case of unit testing a mailer, you're mostly focused on the correct generation of the content. Testing of successful delivery or use in jobs, controllers, etc., would be done as part of request or feature tests.

Comment: thanks! I got it solved but just saw this solution and did end up doing something very similar to this.

Answer (score 2):

Before testing it, make sure the `config / environment / test.rb` file is set to:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

This ensures that emails are not actually sent, but are stored in the `ActionMailer :: Base.deliveries` array.

Following [Four-Phase Test](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/four-phase-test) :

**animal_mailer.rb**

```
class AnimalMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'noreply@animal_mailer.com'

  def daily_message(owner)
    @name = owner.name

    mail(
      to: owner.email,
      subject: "test",
      content_type: "text/html",
      date: Time.now.in_time_zone("Mountain Time (US & Canada)")
    )
  end
end
```

**animal_mailer_spec.rb**

```
RSpec.describe AnimalMailer, type: :mailer do
  describe 'instructions' do
    let(:user) { create(:user, :admin) }
    let(:mail) { described_class.daily_message(user).deliver_now }

    it 'renders the subject' do
      expect(mail.subject).to eq("test")
    end

    it 'renders the receiver email' do
      expect(mail.to).to eq([user.email])
    end

    it 'renders the sender email' do
      expect(mail.from).to eq(['noreply@animal_mailer.com'])
    end

    it 'assigns @name' do
      expect(mail.body.encoded).to match(user.name)
    end
  end
end
```

if you have a model user:

```
class User
  def send_instructions
    AnimalMailer.instructions(self).deliver_now
  end
end


RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  subject { create :user }

  it 'sends an email' do
    expect { subject.send_instructions }
      .to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
  end
end
```